# Cannot connect to broker error, connection reset by peer

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

When I tail my celeryd I get:

```
consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@[NEW_INSTANCE_IP]:5672//: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer.
Trying again in 32.00 seconds...
```

When I tail my flowerd I get:

```
[DEBUG 2020-01-13 22:31:39,900] events.py [:133] on_enable_events: Failed to enable events: '[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer'
```

I have tried both 
`sudo invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start` and `sudo rabbitmqctl start_app`

I have been working on this issue all day and can't seem to figure it out. It started off updating my instance where I had to change my `BROKER_URL` to `amqp://guest:**[NEW_INSTANCE_IP]:5672` and ever since nothing has been working right. I am fairly new to utilizing rabbitmq, celery and supervisord. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstall..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to change "[NEW_INSTANCE_IP]" to the actual ip of your broker url. For most configurations this is usually just localhost.
Try changing to this.

`broker_url = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost'`